# Step up converter for TV and home cinema set

Tags: electrical

Soon I will move from Europe to Canada and I am planning to take my TV and home cinema set with me.

TV is a Techwood (Samsung panel) LCD TV with the specs:

On the back of the TV it says: 220V-240V 50Hz 250W

The home theater set is a Yamaha YHT-394.

Written on the back of the receiver is: 230V 50Hz 250W

There is an active subwoofer with the set which states: 230V 50Hz 45W

Now the total is 545W so I assum that a 1000W step up converter is enough.

But will I get problems with the 50/60Hz conversion? NTSC/PAL is ofcourse not a problem anymore but I am a bit worried about the HZ (especially TV).

Comment: I'm not sure European audio systems are compatible with Geddy Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These electronics have rectifiers internally to turn the input into DC so the frequency won't make any noticeable difference.  However, if your transformer is not "clean" then you are will get a lot of extra noise in your sound system; make sure it's a good one.